# Can I get `firebase deploy` to first run `yarn build` before starting the upload?

Tags: firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

As a developer, 
to correctly deploy my React project,
I would like `firebase deploy --only hosting` to automatically run `yarn build` before starting the upload

Answer (score 8):

I found out that there is a "predeploy" hook that works!

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "predeploy": [
      "cd client && yarn run build"
    ],
    "public": "client/build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "yarn build && firebase deploy --only hosting"
  },
}
```

Then you can run `npm run deploy` from the command line.

Comment: Works if you have deploy keys locally. In my case the deploy keys must be protected, in the cloud. Also Firebase bugs means we must use a custom firebase-action Docker image that contains a `firebase` command of a version that works.